# The scrollviewer "locks" when scrolling vertically or horizontally

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, locking, windows-phone, scrollview

If I start the scrolling vertically or horizontically the scroller "locks", such that you can only scroll horizontically or vertically, untill you let go. If I however start of by scrolling diagonally, there is no problem, in thhese cases I can manouvre the scrollviewer how i want. How do I make sure that the scrollViewer doesn't "lock" if I start of scrolling vertically or horizontically. Here is my scrollViewer:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock x:Name="MainPageTitle" Text="{Binding title}" Height="89"/>

    <ScrollViewer Width="768" Height="380" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <Map/>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <TextBlock x:Name="LEgE" Text="HEJHEJEHEJEHJEHJ"/>


</StackPanel>
```

So just to clarify, how do I make sure that no matter how I start of the scroll, I'm always capable of scrolling in any direction. With in the grid of course. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What if you set the vertivcalscrollbarvisibility also?

Comment: You say "If I however start of by scrolling diagonally" - how do you scroll diagonally in the stock WPF ScrollViewer? More over, how do you scroll horizontally, if `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"`? I think we are missing some info here.

Comment: @XAMeLi that is obvious t is windows phone 8 application

Comment: I might have forgotten to mention it, nut ja, it's for a windows phone 8 app

Comment: Doh!... Missed the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known  Issue that the scrollviewer runs on "rails".

Which is also stated in the artikel in msdn forums http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/8fdbe189-c037-4f55-89c5-6d6814dc58f2/scrollviewer-locks-when-you-only-scroll-horizontally-or-vertically?forum=wpdevelop

But one could look at how to handle manipulation events for windows phone
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff426933(v=vs.105).aspx

For this you need to set ScrollViewer.ManipulationMode to Control and manage it yourself.

But as stated in the first link, to acheive smoothness is very hard.