# Disable diagonal panning in nested FlipView

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

My XAML roughly looks as follows.

```
<FlipView>
    <FlipViewItem>
        <Grid Height="400" Background="Blue"/>
    </FlipViewItem>
    <FlipViewItem>
        <Grid>
            <FlipView x:Name="DigestFlipView" Style="{StaticResource DigestViewStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
    </FlipViewItem>
</FlipView>
```

And then in my `DigestViewStype` I have made it vertical as follows:

```
<Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

What I want is, when swipe is vertical, *only* inner `FlipView` should kick in. Also, when swipe is horizontal, *only* outer `FlipView` should kick in.

I get the desired behavior if I replace inner `FlipView` with a `ListView`. `ListView` scrolls for vertical swipes and `FlipView` for horizontal ones. I have tried playing with templates with no luck. Is there a way to achieve what I need with `FlipView`s?

Comment: First thought, capture the touch events on the page itself and detect the direction. Depending on that trigger the correct event on the correct control. Maybe this will help https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Manipulations-and-gestures-362b6b59

Comment: @Depechie My first thought too. But wouldn't that involve doing *everything* manually? This will include handling snap points, continuous manipulation, overscrolling, inertia and what not. Likely to degrade performance!

Comment: I know :/ that is why I didn't set it as answer, would hope something easier would be possible

Comment: @Depechie My problem is also how `ListView` is handling it easily! I mean, it's got it's own `ScrollViewer` too!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The scrollviewer "locks" when scrolling vertically or horizontally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592285/the-scrollviewer-locks-when-scrolling-vertically-or-horizontally)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592285/the-scrollviewer-locks-when-scrolling-vertically-or-horizontally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ScrollViewer` can scroll horizontally. A `ScrollViewer` can scroll vertically. And, a `ScrollViewer` can scroll both horizontally and vertically - you are calling this third case "diagonal" scrolling.

A `ScrollViewer` has a feature where once it starts scrolling either horizontally or vertically, it will no longer scroll the opposite. It sounds like this is what you want. This feature is called "rails".

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.ishorizontalrailenabled.aspx
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.isverticalrailenabled.aspx